# Is there a way to run initial python commands for debug tasks?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

Whenever I "Run and Debug" one of my Python files in VS Code, like this one:

```py
import numpy

a = numpy.arange(1000)

print("Hello World!")  # <-- Breakpoint here
```

I'd like to have a few Python commands run first so they are "active" for the current session in the Debug Console, e.g., printing options like

```py
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=200, threshold=5000)
```

such that printed output in the Debug Console is more useful, e.g., if I type `a` in the Debug Console, I do want long lines as with the print options set.

I know one can run predefined tasks (via `tasks.json`) via the `launch.json`, but they run in an independent terminal, so they as far as I know can not be set up to affect the actual Python debug session. Is there a way to achieve this?

I'm aware that this could mess with the code, e.g., if somebody imported something else as `np`, but I'd be willing to take that risk.

Comment: Can you describe your needs in more detail? Or provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, [`tasks.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks) might help you.

Comment: @JialeDu Thanks for your response; I tried to make my question a little bit more clear, but I can't provide a MRE, sadly, as this is mostly a VS Code interface question. Is it understandable now?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following configuration.

```
"type": "python",
"request": "launch",
"code": [
   "import runpy, numpy",
   "numpy.set_printoptions(linewidth=200, threshold=5000)",
   "runpy.run_path('foo')", 
],
```

Comment: Thanks. It does in principle work if you replace `'foo'` with `r'${file}'`, although unfortunately my scripts do not run with the limitations of runpy because they spawn additional processes.